# Pinescript Strategy Labels Modification

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm newer to Pinescript and have a working strategy, but I'd like more info on the label to help with my tracking and backtesting. I would like to be able to modify the Signal Label of the closed trades to also have how many pips were made or lost for each trade. Currently, it just says "Close entry(s) order Long". Is there a way to make it show for example "Close entry(s) order Long -23.5 Pips" or something similar to that. I am using strategy.close and I imagine this can be done by adding a comment, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreciated. If I can't do this, I would add a label instead if I can figure that out. This isn't vital to get the strategy to work, but will save me lots of time when I document the previous weeks trades.

```
if LongCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if LongExit
    strategy.close("Long")
if ShortCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
if ShortExit
    strategy.close("Short")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes use the **comment** parameter for that
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose)

Example:

```
if LongExit
    strategy.close("Long", comment = "Close Long " + str.tostring(strategy.openprofit, "#.##"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, is there a way to convert this to pip value?

Comment: yes you can multiply this value by the pip() function

pip() => syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)

str.tostring(strategy.openprofit * pip(), "#.##"))

Comment: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-calculate-using-pips

Comment: That didn't work for me. All of the trades are returning "Close Long 0" regardless of how much they made unless I make the order size pretty big. Code I'm using:  pip() => syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)

if (LongCondition and SourceTypeExit)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (LongExit and SourceTypeExit)
    strategy.close("Long", comment = "Close Long " + str.tostring(strategy.openprofit * pip(), "#.##"))

Comment: Try this please. Will work only with a V5 pine script.

strategy.close("Long", comment = "Close Long " + str.tostring(strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades - 1),  "#.##"))

Comment: Documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}opentrades{dot}profit

Comment: That returns 0.01. I feel like it shouldn't be tied to opentrades.profit because that is subjective in each market. I'm trying to get it to have exit price minus entry price, but I can't quite get the exit price. I can only get the exit price of the previous trade. This is what I'm using: strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1) which is not the current trades price.

Comment: For me the current trade profit is returned by strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades - 1)
What asset are you running your strategy on?

Comment: I don't know why it's working better today, but it's still slightly off. The Price Range tool, snapping to the candles shows me 56.0 pips, but the comment says 56.45. Another shows 26.9 on the tool, but the comment says 27.28. It's much close now, but for some reason just a little off. This is only if I'm using 1 contract.